# XSL:Copy specific attribute and value from one node to another

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

In the original XML file, the node /XMLLandedCostOutput/AgentInvoiceCollection/AgentInvoice/DocumentNumber/ holds a #text value (for example: "JIN83776".

What I would like to do is to copy the said JIN83776 entry to a child node /XMLLandedCostOutput/AgentInvoiceCollection/AgentInvoice/AgentInvoiceLineCollecton/AgentInvoiceLine/ and name it "DocumentNumberCopy" (which must then have the DocumentNumber value JIN83776).

I currently have in my xsl the following:  (The "DocumentNumberCopy" attribute entry gets created; but holds no value):

```
<DocumentNumberCopy>
<xls:value-of select=".DocumentNumber"/>
</DocumentNumbrCopy?
```

I require assistance with the syntax of incorporating the xls:copy method  to achieve this and any assistance will be immensely appreciated.

Created a xsl file which succesfully creates the  entry within the child; but the entry contains no value.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: If you are in a template matching AgentInvoice you should write <xls:value-of select="DocumentNumber"/> ; at upper level : <xls:value-of select=".//DocumentNumber"/> ; somewhere else <xls:value-of select="//DocumentNumber"/>